# Umbraco 4.8, Document save Publish

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

Umbraco 4.8 had bug in umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.Publish method?
I try to edit a node, save and Publish a node.
I can look in BackOffice that the node is changed correctly.
In web page, I use razor to render to HTML. This cshtml file use umbrac.MacroEngines.DynamicNode. This node version returns the old value.
Then, in BackOffice, I try to click "Salve and Publish", then webpage render the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DynamicNode` accesses the node's information from the `umbraco.config` cache, it doesn't directly access the database (See [Difference between Node and Document](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document)). Saving and Publishing do not update the cache by themselves, there is an additional step.
Example:

```
Document document = new Document(1234);
document.Text = "New Title";
document.Publish(User.GetUser(0));    
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(document.Id);
```

See [Publishing and republishing](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/publishing-and-republishing) for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks.

I create another question:
[Umbraco: differences between Node, DynamicNode, Content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420707/umbraco-differences-between-node-dynamicnode-content).

Can you help me?